# implementing KeyListener

Tags: java, keylistener

I am trying to test out the KeyListener class - when a key is /pressed/typed/released something is printed, also how could I listen for a specific letter e.g. when 'n' is pressed something is printed.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Test2 implements KeyListener {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("hello1");
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `KeyEvent.getKeyCode()` along with the constants defined in `KeyEvent` for the various characters on a keyboard.

For example,

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_N) {
         System.out.println("n Pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With either

```
if(event.getKeyChar() == 'n')
     // do stuff
```

Or

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KV_N)
    // do stuff
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there something wrong with my code ? because it doesn't work for me.  i.e nothing is being printed when I press down a key.

Comment: Have you registered the `KeyListener`?

Comment: I have tried - adding addKeyListener(this) in the constructor of above class.

Comment: on what object did you call `addKeyListener()`? I think its better to follow a small [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to get things going. Without knowing the very basics, its impossible to discover/learn about these kind of things.